# Finding the nearest space before a specific count of characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find any addresses in ADDRESS_1 that is over 20 characters and split it by the nearest space before that 20 character limit into the blank ADDRESS_2 column.

For example:

```
Address_1: 14256 Canyonville Drive apt 23
```

would become

```
Address_1: 14256 Canyonville
Address_2: Drive apt 23
```

I know this is a super dumb thing to have to do but unfortunately the system I'm working in limits Address_1 to 20 characters and I have to be doing all my data transformations within SQL Server.

Comment: IMHO this could be written in a few minutes with a scripting language like php, python, bash ..   Writing that query just looks .. Hard.

Comment: Yup, agreed. I literally have a python script written but since my workflow (currently) is entirely within SQL I have to use it for the time being. My hope is that showing how complex this is will get me a little more support transitioning our work flow to Python instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a SQL only solution:

```sql
select Address_1 as Original_Address_1
     , iif(l <= 20, Address_1, rtrim(substring(Address_1, 1, i))) as Address_1
     , iif(l <= 20, '', ltrim(substring(Address_1, i+1, 200))) as Address_2
  from (
        select Address_1
             , 20 - charindex(' ', reverse(substring(Address_1, 1, 20))) as i
             , len(Address_1) as l
        from @table) a;
```

OUTPUT

```
Original_Address_1             Address_1                      Address_2
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
14256 Canyonville Drive apt 23 14256 Canyonville              Drive apt 23
123 Small St                   123 Small St                   
123ReallyBigNoSpaceStreet      123ReallyBigNoSpaceS           treet

(3 rows affected)
```

Comment: would that work with with strings over 40 characters?

Comment: yes, it should work for strings up to 200 characters. it's limited by `substring(... 200)` in line 3.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION AddressSlap (@address varchar(256)) RETURNS TABLE 
AS
BEGIN
    IF LEN(@address) < 20
    BEGIN
        SELECT @address AS Address
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @s int
        SELECT @s = 20 - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(@address, 20)), 0)

        SELECT LEFT(@address, @s) AS Address
        UNION
        SELECT RIGHT(@address, LEN(@address) - @s)
    END
END
```

which you can then use with `CROSS APPLY`.